# Apache Echart: set axis label interval when both axis are type 'value'

Tags: echarts

I have a bar graph, with both xAxis and yAxis of type 'value'.

I'm trying to set the interval of the label/ticks to shows the label for each data on the xAxis.

Using `axisLabel: { interval: 1 }` **doesn't work**.
Using `axisTick: { interval: 1 }`  **doesn't work**.

I can't change the xAxis to type 'category', because I need to use it for a mark area.
Here the basic code that i'm using:

```
    grid: chartGrid,
    title: {
      left: 'center',
    },
    tooltip: {
      ...
    },
    toolbox: {
      ...
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'value',
      axisLabel: {
        show: true,
        interval: 1,
        formatter: (value:any, index:any) => {...},
      },
      axisTick: {
        interval:1
      }
    },
    yAxis: { type: 'value'},
    
    series: {
      name: 'Total',
      type: 'bar',
      itemStyle: {
        borderRadius: [10, 10, 0, 0],
        color: 'rgb(54, 81, 83)',
      },
      barGap: '-100%',
      data: [
          [1,2],
          [3,7],
          [5,6],
          ...
      ],
      large: true,
      markArea: markAreaData,
    }
}
```

And this is how the chart is displayed:

[image]

How can I set the interval of the label/ticks to shows the label for each data on the xAxis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using echarts 5.4.1 and at the time the library was bugged
https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/18130

I solved my problem (and in my opinion is the best approach when using MarkArea) using a 'value' axis and a 'category' axis, and simply specifing on 'xAxis' and 'yAxis' the values that define the range.